UK State pension rules
I enquired about the amount of UK state pension that I would receive due to my pension contributions. I received advice from a government employee claiming that I would receive the full state pension with 29 years contributions. I can’t find anything in an internet search that confirms or contradicts this.
Question: Does anyone have a reference about the actual rules that apply? There is official government information which is just very vague.

You can check this online: https://www.tax.service.gov.uk/check-your-state-pension/account It will tell you how much you can expect to receive, and how many more years of contributions you need to make to receive it (if any).

@SteveMelnikoff I've seen that site. It gives me a forecast which claims I'll get the full state tax with 29 years of contributions. Frankly, I don't trust it. And I don't think anyone will give me a penny if I wave the forecast around when I get actually paid less money. A site that tells the actual rules used would be much appreciated.

You could read The State Pension Regulations 2015 which states "The State Pension Regulations 2015 is up to date with all changes known to be in force on or before 18 October 2024." Happy reading! AFAIK it's also possible to get a pension forecast in writing. Another option is to visit the Citizen's Advice Bureau.
